# Remove default dropdown option added by required true in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I have a select dropdown option that is required but its option are dynamically added. So there's a scenario wherein the select dropdown is empty.

```
= s.input :test_id, :label => "Choose Category", :collection => @model.categories, :required => true
```

My question is how can I remove the blank option added automatically when you set your dropdown as required (I wanted my dropdown to be empty). I've tried adding `include_blank: false` but I'm getting an `ArgumentError - include_blank cannot be false for a required field.:`

Answer (score 1):

Should work with:

```
= s.input :test_id, :label => "Choose Category", :collection => @model.categories, :required => true, prompt: ''
```